# Column collapsible to a button on mobile

Tags: responsive-design, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I have a 2 columns page and I want that on small screens the first column to be replaced by a small column with just a button on it. When you click the button the original first column appears again (like it is on Wordpress for example).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot reduce a column into a button on a breakpoint (not without adding a lot of code), but you can:

- Add a new column with `class="column small-12 hide-for-medium"`, and put the button there... this will keep the column hidden from medium up.
- The collapsible column (the first one) will have the class `hide-for-small-only`, so this will be hidden on small breakpoint; please add an **id** to this column.
- Using jQuery, on the button click, hide/show the first column (the one with the ID, you sould use `slideToggle() from jQuery`), and that's it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you!, I got it working with a solution like this.

Comment: Excellent!... glad to be helpful